# Alternative Blas with rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, blas

I currently have an R-3.0.2 that I built from source on a RHEL6 machine with the command `./configure --prefix=/opt/${name}-%{version} --with-blas --with-lapack --with-x --enable-R-shlib` so that R uses the system ones for the extra speed. When I attempt to install rstudio it complains that libRblas.so and libRlapack.so are missing because I am not using the packaged R libraries. How can I link rstudio with the system blas instead of the slower R ones?